# subtract "1" from the number in a row SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I just want to know how to subtract 1 from the number that appears in $row[posts_remaining]

In other words...

---

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect($db_server_name,$db_username,$db_password);
if (!$con) {
    //do something
}
mysql_select_db("" . $db_database_name . "", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
WHERE fb_id='$user_id'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $posts_remaining = $row['posts_remaining']
    // this is where I want to subtract 1 and then update "posts_remaining" with the new number
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

---

This will give me my result where row posts_remaining = {THE NUMBER}

But I want to update that returned number by subtracting one from it and then SETting the new number in back where the old number was.

I hope Im not making this confusing.  It's hard to explain.

Additionally... should I have the row "posts_remaining" set as something other than TEXT in order to do this....  like Char(50) or something or is it ok to leave it as TEXT?

Comment: IF you're using a database column to store numbers, then DON'T MAKE IT A TEXT FIELD

Comment: Ok that still didn't tell me WHAT to make it or answer my initial question.  But ok.

Comment: @user2284703 I think it quite clearly suggests that if you're dealing with integers, the INT types are probably a good way to go... (note: there are multiple that you may want to look at, TINYINT, SMALLINT, MEDIUMINT, INT, BIGINT - depending on how large you invisage the numbers in the column being)

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to modify the type of the field from text to integer 
Than for update records try this query

```
update users
set
posts_remaining= posts_remaining - 1
WHERE fb_id='your_user_id'
```

Comment: I see where I went wrong.  Youre code was right.  I just had the wrong variable for the user id.  Was using $user_id when I was supposed to be using $f_userid.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using database query itself:

```
mysql_query("Update users set posts_remaining = posts_remaining -1 where fb_id='$user_id'");
```

Comment: I dont know but none of these suggestions seem to be working.  Wish I knew what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The column type has to be an integer, not string, you'll have to edit that.
You can use

```sql
UPDATE users SET posts_remaining = posts_remaining -1 where fb_id = '$user_id'
```

You are also susceptible to SQL injection attacks, and you should look into prepared statements to reduce the impact of these attacks
(https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)